# embed image to body in html email in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How shall i write the code to embed image to email body? whats wrong?

```
     mMailMessage.Body += Server.MapPath(@"<img src=""/Styles/Images/logo.png""");
```

.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping a path to a file called `"<img src=""/Styles/Images/logo.png"""`!

What you want to do is something like this:

```
mMailMessage.Body += "<img src=\"" + Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + ":" + Request.Url.Port + @"/Styles/Images/logo.png" + "\"/>";
```

Comment: I forgot to escape the quotes. Try it now.